# Why Can't I Select != Nvarchar?

Tags: sql, sql-server

As you can see in the image below, if I perform the following query I get at least 10 results:

```
SELECT TOP (10) [t0].[u_nonreportable]
FROM [sdidataitem] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[u_nonreportable] IS NULL
```

[image]

By contrast, if I simply perform a query like this, I get no results:

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 NVarChar(1000) = 'Y'
-- EndRegion
SELECT TOP (10) [t0].[u_nonreportable]
FROM [sdidataitem] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[u_nonreportable] <> @p0
```

[image]

If there are results where **[u_nonreportable] is null**, then why don't I get any results when I say **[u_nonreportable] != 'Y'**?

Note: I am using LINQPad in the examples above; however, I have also confirmed the results by running the SQL queries in SSMS.

Comment: Because in sql NULL never ever equals anything...and it also doesn't NOT equal anything. Because it is NULL it means unknown, therefore it is logically impossible to know or not know if the value is in fact 'Y'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer lies in the semantics of `NULL`s in SQL Server.  Both `NULL = NULL` and `NULL != NULL` are false.  So, when you say `[u_nonreportable] != 'Y'`, the result is false when `[u_nonreportable]` is `NULL`.

More specifically, the above semantics are true when `ANSI_NULLS` is set to `ON`, which is [the default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-nulls-transact-sql) and soon to be only value.

Comment: Great answer, very interesting. So, in my case, I would likely want to check that it's not null and then check if it's not equal to Y like `[u_nonreportable] != null and [u_nonreportable] != 'Y'` that way it will short circuit if it's null?

Comment: Try this: WHERE ISNULL([t0].[u_nonreportable], 'N') <> @p0

Comment: Both of these are `unknown` not `false`. If they were false putting a `not` in front of them would make them true. SQL uses [three valued logic](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-and-the-snare-of-three-valued-logic/)

Comment: @user1477388 No problem! I kind of assumed your NULLS were equivalent to "N" since you are looking for "Y", you can change that value as needed though.

Comment: @user1477388 You can do what Jacob describes, or use `[u_nonreportable] IS NULL OR [u_nonreportable] != 'Y'`.  Basically, always compare to null using `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`.  Incidentally, booleans don't short-circuit in T-SQL as they do in, say, C#, but this doesn't really affect the query semantics.